# TSQL MAX OF A SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2008

I have a table of sales orders structured like this

```
PartNo  Desc      OrderDate      OrderQty
60001   widget1   Apr-02-2012    3
60001   widget1   Apr-14-2012    5
60001   widget1   Jun-04-2012    3
60002   widget2   Jan-03-2012    1
60002   widget2   jan-17-2012    1
60002   widget2   aug-04-2012    30
60002   widget2   sep-02-2012    1
60003   widget3   oct-01-2012    4
60003   widget3   oct-04-2012    7
60003   widget3   oct-17-2012    3
60004   widget4   nov-04-2011    8
60004   widget4   nov-05-2011    8
60004   widget4   nov-05-2012    8
60004   widget4   nov-07-2012    7
```

I want to return a table that is the max of the total per month for each item.  It would look like this

```
PartNo    Desc     MaxSoldPerMonth  Month  Year
60001     widget1  8                Apr    2012
60002     widget2  30               Aug    2012
60003     widget3  14               oct    2012
60004     widget4  16               nov    2011
```

the months are actually in number format(i.e. nov = 11, oct = 10, apr = 4, ect)  i just made it this way to make it easy to read.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
;WITH MonthlyOrders AS
(
    SELECT PartNo, [Desc], CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),OrderDate,112) YearMonth, SUM(OrderQty) OrderQty
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY PartNo, [Desc], CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),OrderDate,112)
),MaxOrders AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PartNo, [Desc] ORDER BY OrderQty DESC) RN
    FROM MonthlyOrders
)
SELECT PartNo, [Desc], OrderQty MaxSoldPerMonth, YearMonth
FROM MaxOrders
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: @bluefeet well, I was bored ;-)

Comment: This worked...Thanks!  What are these over(partition ) RN statements called so I can look into them?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following:

```
;with cte as
(
  select partno, 
    [desc], 
    sum(orderqty) total,
    datename(month, orderdate) month, 
    year(orderdate) year,
    row_number() over(partition by partno order by sum(orderqty) desc) rn
  from yourtable
  group by partno, [desc],
    datename(month, orderdate), year(orderdate)
) 
select partno, [desc], total, month, year
from cte
where rn = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d4a7/13)

Comment: +1 Never knew you could use `sum` on the `order by` part of the `row_number`.

Comment: @Lamak I didn't know until I tried it. :)  I was actually expecting an error and was surprised when it worked.